# My file doesn't return the magic file message

Tags: linux, file

I have to create a magic file that can detect a result of 42 on the 42nd byte.
I've created the following line to then compile

```
40 search 42 this is a 42 file
```

but when I run `file -m <file_name>` with this content

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00042
```

I get the message

```
Warning: type `00000000 00000000 00000000 00042' invalid
file: could not find any valid magic files! (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your magic should be like this:

```
0 search/42 42 File containing "42"
!:mime text/x-42
```

Here's my test:

```
x@ubuntu:~$ cat testfile.txt 
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00042
x@ubuntu:~$ file -m magicfile.mgc testfile.txt 
testfile.txt: File containing "42", ASCII text
x@ubuntu:~$
```